# Access request or response in a function where it does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm 'modularizing' my application and I am using a Promise to pull data from my database inside my controller. After the data is back I want to deal with the response in another function:

Inside my controller i have:

```
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    model: Event,
    sort: {},
    limit: {},
    options: {}
  };

  database(options)
    .then(handleResponse.ok)
    .then(undefined, handleResponse.error);
```

And in the handleResponse file:

```
var response = {
  ok: function(result, res) {
    if (!result) {
      return false;
    }

    response.json(result);
  },
  error: function (error) {
    if (!error) {
      return false;
    }

    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  }
};

module.exports = response;
```

But the response.json is undefined. There is anyway that i can access the request and response inside the handleResponse file?

Comment: "But the response.json is undefined". What do you expect? The object doesn't have such method.

Comment: that's why i ask if there is anyway that i can access the request and response inside the handleResponse file..

Comment: Your handleResponse has no access to the actual express response object.  If your controller function has access to it you can pass it into your handleresponse.

Comment: You have to pass them in as parameters.

Comment: Anything you want to access from within a function needs to either be passed to that function or the function needs to be declared internal to that scope so it can access parent arguments.  For a more complete answer, please include the code that initiates the request (e.g. where request and response are declared).